# DI with Dagger2, add to or get from the graph?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, architecture, dagger-2

Using Dagger2, what are the pros and cons of the 2 following implementations:

1)

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Something something;
    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        something = ((MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext())
            .getComponent().getSomething();
    }
}

@Component
public interface MyComponent() {
    Something getSomething();
}
```

2)

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Inject Something something;
    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ((MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext())
            .getComponent().inject(this);
    }
}

@Component
public interface MyComponent() {
    void inject(MyReceiver myReceiver);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*tl;dr* Go for Option 2. `@Inject` your fields.

If your object can be created by injecting into the constructor (sample below), definitely go for **Option 2**, since you will *not* have to write any code other than marking the constructor to use with `@Inject`.

```
// object can just be injected without any additional modules
// since all dependencies can be satisfied
public class Something {
    @Inject
    public Something() {}
}
```

So to further answer the question let us concentrate on field / method injection.

Just using `@Inject` annotations will keep your code simpler. **Option 2** will let you again just declare dependencies.

```
// dont't worry about where they come from
// or how they are created 
@Inject
Something mSomething;

@Inject
Foo mFoo;

public void onCreate() {
    ((Application) context.getApplicationContext())
        .getComponent().inject(this);
}
```

Also, for testing purposes you might want to override the injected fields, by just injecting the same object again with your TestComponent. This also is only possible with **Option 2**.

```
@Test
void someTest() {
    // this is only possible with @Injected annotated fields
    testComponent.inject(activityUnderTest);
}
```

### But the first option!

The **1. Option** will mostly be used to *expose dependencies* for dependent components, not to be confused with `SubComponent` components, which will always have full access to the parent graph.

```
@Component
public interface MyComponent() {
    Something getSomething(); // exposes something
}

@Component(dependencies = {MyComponent.class})
public interface OtherComponent() {
    // can access something in modules
}
```

Using Option 1 manually would mean to handle the dependency injection yourself by programmatically fetching dependencies from actual business code and writing harder to test code, which you are trying to avoid by using DI.

Comment: I've been using a bit of both. If many `Receiver` need the same object, then I create a `BaseReceiver`, and add it to the graph, to avoid having many `void inject(XXx)`.